# PyQt TreeWidget Smooth updating (model-view?)

Tags: pyqt, qtreeview, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I am trying to update a QTreeWidget every 60 seconds. I have it on a QTimer right now but my concern is that when it updates it will disrupt the users progress(for example if they have a parent opened up so you can see the children, when I update it completely resets the structure). Is there a model or anything I can do to prevent this from hurting their progress?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for the view to update and remember the previously expanded items. You could cache the state of your view and reconstruct it with `QTreeWidget::expand` and `QTreeWidget::scrollTo` after an update, but the user will still see how the view closes and expands again. Also, it would not be enough to store the currently expanded item's index because that might change after the update. So you'd have to cache some unique identifier and search it in the upated widget afterwards.

What you are trying to do, is quite unusual, since normally you'd only update the widget when the data changes instead of using a fixed interval of time.

Consider using a QTreeView in combination with a QAbstractListModel instead of a QTreeWidget because the latter is designed to hold constant data. Then you can emit dataChanged on the model which automatically updates the QTreeView.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think I will try to implement a TreeView and update it when the data changes. I'll let you know how it goes.